# D3js - Getting max value from d3.line() for a specific domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making a multi-line chart and I have implemented a brush to be able to zoom into a specific domain on the x-axis. However, when I zoom in I want the y-axis to scale along so that its domain goes from `[0, maxY]`, where `maxY` is the maximum y-value for the current selection on the x-axis. To generate the lines I am using `d3.line()` (which has the connection between the x and y values). This is how I currently calculate the `maxY` value:

```
//Find max and min values in data to set the domain of the y-axis
var maxArray = updatedData.map(function(variable){
  //First map the values in the array to a new array
  var valuesArray = variable.values.map(function(d){
    return d.value;
  })
  //Find max value in array
  return Math.max(...valuesArray);
});
var maxY = Math.max(...maxArray);
```

And here is where I set the scales and create the `d3.line()`:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([0, chartWidth]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, maxY])
  .range([chartHeight, 0]);

var brush = d3.brushX()
  .on("end", brushend);

var line = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveBasis)
  .x(function(d) {return xScale(d.date)})
  .y(function(d) {return yScale(d.value)})

//Save this to be able to zoom back out
var originalDomain = [new Date(data[0].Timestamp), new Date(data[data.length-1].Timestamp)];
xScale.domain(originalDomain);
```

Here is the code where I set the new `xScale.domain()` and zoom in on that interval (which is called when the brushing is ended):

```
function brushend(){
  //sourceEvent - the underlying input event, such as mousemove or touchmove.
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush
  var brushInterval = d3.event.selection; //The interval of the current brushed selection
  //If the function is called with no selection: ignore
  if(!brushInterval) return;
  //Enable reset button
  resetButton.attr("disabled", null)
    .on("click", resetAxis);

  var newDomain = brushInterval.map(xScale.invert, xScale);

  //TODO: Find max and min values in data to set the domain of the y-axis

  xScale.domain(newDomain);
  chart.selectAll(".line")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
      .attr("d", function(d){ return line(d.values)});
  chart.select(".x-axis")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
      .call(xAxis);
  //Remove the visual brush
  d3.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null);
}
```

What I would like to do is to find the maximum y-value in the currently selected domain. I know that I can filter the data values to remove the ones that are not in the currently selected domain and then calculate the maximum value from them (like I did for the original domain). But it seems like there should be an easier solution to this. I didn't find any function in the documentation for `d3.line()` that could calculate max values.

Is there any easy way to calculate max value from `d3.line()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not really an *easier solution to this* as you somehow have to filter the values to only take into account the ones which are in your selected x domain. However, using two nested calls to [`d3.max()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#max) you can at least give it a pleasant look and spare some iterations by avoiding an additional call to `.filter()`. Since `d3.max()` will ignore `null` values you can use it to filter your values by returning `null` if the current datum is outside of the x domain's boundaries. To get the maximum value you can use something like the following:

```
const maxY = xDomain => d3.max(updatedData, variable => 
  d3.max(
    variable.values,
    v => v.Timestamp >= xDomain[0] && v.Timestamp <= xDomain[1] ? v.value : null
  )
);
```

Have a look at the following snippet for a working demo:

```js
var updatedData = [{
  values: [{Timestamp:0, value:1},{Timestamp:1, value:5},{Timestamp:2, value:10},{Timestamp:3, value:3},{Timestamp:4, value:30}]
}, {
  values: [{Timestamp:0, value:19},{Timestamp:1, value:12},{Timestamp:2, value:13},{Timestamp:3, value:8},{Timestamp:4, value:50}]
}];

const maxY = xDomain => d3.max(updatedData, variable => 
  d3.max(
    variable.values,
    v => (!xDomain || v.Timestamp >= xDomain[0] && v.Timestamp <= xDomain[1]) ? v.value : null
  )
);

console.log(maxY());       // Default, check all values: max 50
console.log(maxY([1,3]));  // Max 13
console.log(maxY([0,3]));  // Max 19
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```